# Geometry of Right angled isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

So I was solving problems on Pythagoras' Theorem and I started wondering about the following:
Imagine we have a triangle $ABC$ right-angled at $A.$ So, we can say that $\angle B = \angle C = 45.$ Now if we make a line segment $AD$ where D is an arbitrary point on the hypotenuse. Now if we compare $ACD$ and $ADB,$ we can say that $AD = AD$, $\angle DBA = \angle ACD = 45$ and $AC = AB$, so $ACD$ and $ADB$ should be congruent, right?

Comment: This is precisely why SSA is not one of the triangle congruence cases. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Similarity_and_congruence): "*Side-Side-Angle (or Angle-Side-Side) condition: If two sides and a corresponding non-included angle of a triangle have the same length and measure ... then this is not sufficient to prove congruence ... The Side-Side-Angle condition does not by itself guarantee that the triangles are congruent because one triangle could be obtuse-angled and the other acute-angled.*".

Comment: Ohh... thanks for clearing my query!